# How do I go back to editing a file after playing a game in emacs without having to quit emacs?

Tags: emacs, terminal

Sorry, noob here

So if I were to edit a file with emacs, then I feel like playing a game, let's say snake.  So I type (esc), x, snake.  Then if I want to go back to editing my code, I would have to quit emacs, and re-open the file. How to I go back to editing without having to quit emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to a buffer by pressing <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, or you can press <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd> to get a list of all existing buffers, from which you can select by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the chosen buffer.

Comment: How do I close the list?

Comment: @chamington: You can either press `q` to make it disappear (but it doesn't close it), or use `C-x k` to kill it.